# UILabel and .usesFontLeading

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, uilabel

I researched a bit and it looks like the default value for NSLayoutManager's .usesFontLeading value is true.

My problem:
I'm using boundingRect to get the size of the text in UILabel with a custom font, the height is correct if I remove `.usesFontLeading` but incorrect if I add that option.

My question:
In UILabel, does the font of my label automatically use my font's leading value? and secondly, am I required to set `.usesFontLeading` as an option in my boundingRect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 extension String {
    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width,
                                    height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect,
                                            options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                            attributes: [.font: font],
                                            context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }
}
```